# Vertically stack 4 tables in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to recreate this structure in matplotlib
[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4) = plt.subplots(ncols=1, nrows=4)
# fig.tight_layout()
ax1.axis("off")
ax2.axis("off")
ax3.axis("off")
ax4.axis("off")

ax1.table(cellText=[["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]])

ax2.table(cellText=[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                    [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
                    [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
                    [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
                    [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
                    [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
                    [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7],
                    [8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8],
                    [9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]])

ax3.table(cellText=[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]])

ax4.table(cellText=[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]])

plt.show()
```

Here is what I have so far, but the tables are overlapping and it's not useable.
So my question is how can I achieve make this table structure in matplotlib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're running into is that `subplots` assumes that all of your tables will be the same size. Since this is not the case, you end up with tables that are larger the the underlying `Axes` objects.

If your case you have your tables in advance so you can estimate their sizes based on the number of rows. You can pass this information into the `subplots` constructor to proportionally resize the returned Axes such that each table *should* fit into their own axes.

Here I predefine all of the tables in an overarching list (for convenience mainly). I can then get the number of rows in each table and pass that to the `height_ratios` gridspec argument such that each produced `Axes` has a size that is proportional to the number of rows in its respective table.

Then I can zip the returned axes with the tables and actually insert the values.

Lastly, you should pass `loc='center'` so each table is actually drawn into the `Axes` instead of below, above, or off to the side.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tables = [
    [["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]],

    [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
     [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
     [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
     [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
     [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
     [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
     [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7],
     [8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8],
     [9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]],

    [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
     [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]],

    [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
]

table_rows = [len(tbl) for tbl in tables]
fig, axes = plt.subplots(
    ncols=1, nrows=len(tables), 
    gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': table_rows}
)
for tbl, ax in zip(tables, axes.flat):
    ax.table(cellText=tbl, loc='center')
    ax.axis('off')

plt.show()
```

[image]